# Table formatting to automatically break text to fit paghe

Tags: tables

I am trying to get a table to fit to the width of the page without simply reducing it in size, i am at a bit of a loss on how to do this, currently my table is as below but it does not format it to fir the page.

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter One: Introduction}                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
    This chapter will introduce the project and provide the,reader with context of the subject along with the reasons for undertaking the,project and an outline of the project contents.                                                           \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Two: Literature Review}                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
    This chapter will review current literature surrounding,the subjects of this project this will explore the current systems and,theoretical systems that form the basis for this project.                                                        \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Three: Technology Review}                                                                                                                                                                                          \\ \hline
    Throughout this chapter will provide a review of the,technology used in current systems and the technology that will be used for,the proposed system.                                                                                           \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Four: Analysis of Current Systems}                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
    In this chapter a comparison of current systems will be,provided to form a platform from which to model the proposed system. This comparison,will be used to model the functionality of the system and methodology used,for testing the system. \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Five: System Analysis and Requirements}                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
    In this chapter the base functionality for the proposed system,will be discussed and a draft of its implementation will be provided in the,form of system and communication diagrams.                                                           \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Six: System Design}                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
    Throughout this chapter the system implementation will be,described and discussed based on the findings from chapter four and chapter,five.                                                                                                     \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Seven: Software}                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \hline
    This chapter will discuss the software and how it was,constructed with reference to functionality and system requirements discussed,in previous chapters.                                                                                       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Eight:Implementation}                                                                                                                                                                                              \\ \hline
    In this chapter the implementation and integration of the,software into the hardware environment will be discussed with further,reasoning into the choices made on both software modelling and hardware,choices for this project.               \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter 9}                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
    Throughout this chapter a set of test methods will be discussed,,and results of these tests will be displayed. The chosen test method for this,project is user interaction dialogues.                                                           \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter 10}                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
    This chapter will include a critical evaluation of the,system as well as any changes and limitations that were experienced along,with how these limitations were dealt with and how the project was adapted to,these changes.                   \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter 11}                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
    In this chapter a conclusion will be drawn, and a review,of the objectives will be carried out to determine if the project achieved the,aims that were set out for it.                                                                          \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Any advice on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `tabularx` environment, you have to use the `X` column type for at least one column. In addition, I suggest adding a small `\extrarowheight`at the top of cells:

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|}
[image]

Comment: Bernard answer is better than what I suggested...

Comment: thanks @Bernard thats done the trick. is the principle for it spanning multiple pages the same?

Comment: For tables spreading over several pages, you have the `xltabular` package and the eponymous environment `xltabular` which brings the `X` column type  to longtable.

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{0.965\textwidth}|}
```

Does the trick...